Wondershaper limits upload incorrectly
I've a hypervisor with Ubuntu Server 18.04 with several VDS servers with public IP addresses and different operating systems. Each of them has its own network interface for hypervisor. Let's call them vboxnet0, vboxnet1, vboxnet2. I want to limit the speed for each of them to 100 mbit/sec both download and upload. So I use:
wondershaper -a vboxnet0 -u 110000 -d 106000
wondershaper -a vboxnet1 -u 110000 -d 106000
wondershaper -a vboxnet2 -u 110000 -d 106000

Download is limited normally. Running Ookla Speedtest on two VDS servers, I see that both servers have a download speed of ~99.8 Mbps in the same time without problems. However, there is a problem with upload speed. When both VDS servers try to load upload, the upload speed of the first server is about 80 Mbps, and the second one is 20 Mbps. When I look at the monitoring of the physical interface of the hypervisor, I see that its upload does not increase above 100 Mbps. Then I tried to manually set the speed limit for the physical interface of the hypervisor to 1 Gbps, then set the limit for the VDS servers to 100 Mbps:
wondershaper -a eth0 -u 1100000 -d 1060000
wondershaper -a vboxnet0 -u 110000 -d 106000
wondershaper -a vboxnet1 -u 110000 -d 106000
wondershaper -a vboxnet2 -u 110000 -d 106000

But in this case, the upload limitation does not work at all for any server.
